# How to override high precedence variables in ansible?

Tags: ansible, global-variables, ansible-2.x

I am trying to override inventory **group_vars/all** variable with **play vars_prompt** variable. Consider code below:

inventory/group_vars/all.yml

```
variable_1: test1
variable_2: test2
```

test.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "variable_1"
      prompt: "Enter variable_1"
      private: no

    - name: "variable_2"
      prompt: "Enter variable_2"
      private: no

- hosts: group_1
  roles:
    - { role: role_1, tags: role_1 }

- hosts: group_2
  roles:
    - { role: role_2, tags: role_2 }
```

roles/role_1/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: role_1 task
  shell: echo "{{ variable_1 }}"
  register: out

- debug:
    msg: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

roles/role_2/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: role_2 task
  shell: echo "{{ variable_2 }}"
  register: out

- debug:
    msg: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

output
    ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts.test test.yml
    Enter variable_1: var1
    Enter variable_2: var2

```
TASK [role_1 : role_1 task] *******************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 15 January 2018  03:42:12 -0800 (0:00:02.915)       0:00:15.048 *****
changed: [xxx.xxx.com]

TASK [role_1 : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 15 January 2018  03:42:13 -0800 (0:00:00.525)       0:00:15.574 *****
ok: [xxx.xxx.com] => {
    "msg": "test1"
}

PLAY [group_2] ********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 15 January 2018  03:42:13 -0800 (0:00:00.051)       0:00:15.625 *****
ok: [xxx.xxx.com]

TASK [role_2 : role_2 task] *******************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 15 January 2018  03:42:15 -0800 (0:00:02.178)       0:00:17.804 *****
changed: [xxx.xxx.com]

TASK [role_2 : debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************
Monday 15 January 2018  03:42:15 -0800 (0:00:00.397)       0:00:18.202 *****
ok: [xxx.xxx.com] => {
    "msg": "test2"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
xxx.xxx.com : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
xxx.xxx.com : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
xxx.xxx.com : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I want to override variable_1 & variable_2 values with the var1 & var2 (Values accepted with vars_prompt) instead of test1 & test2 (Values set at inventory/group_vars/all.yml). Is there any way to override the values? or any other method to share the variables across the different playbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables prompts are Play-bound, so your prompted `variable_1=var` and `variable_2=var` are registered only for the first (empty in your example) play, second and third plays know nothing about this.

Either apply prompts to respective plays, or make run first play against all hosts with `set_fact`, like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "variable_1"
      prompt: "Enter variable_1"
      private: no
    - name: "variable_2"
      prompt: "Enter variable_2"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        variable_1: "{{ variable_1 }}"
        variable_2: "{{ variable_2 }}"

- hosts: group_1
  roles:
    - { role: role_1, tags: role_1 }

- hosts: group_2
  roles:
    - { role: role_2, tags: role_2 }
```

This will define **host facts** `variable_1` and `variable_2` which are host-bound (and survive through several plays) and have higher priority than group vars from inventory.

P.S. if you use tags to execute subset of tasks, make sure that you have those tags for `set_fact` set.